# Arduino: Camera streaming

Tags: bluetooth, android

I want to make Arduino to stream video by camera thru bluetooth to android.

1. Is Arduino powerfull enough to stream it without lag(Sorry if the question is stupid)
2. Are there any good cameras, I have been searching before, but only found        one 0.3 mp camera, so are there other cameras with better quality?
3. What is better, to use Arduino or Rasberry Pi for that job?

Answer (score 3):

1. Not even close
2. In light of 1 it doesn't matter
3. Get a Pi if you want to do video

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a 0.3 MP camera, that means 300,000 pixels. The Arduino (Uno) has a few KB of SRAM, so you need much more. External SRAM might be an option, but even 300.000 pixels need a lot (like multiple 23LC1024 SRAMs).

Also the Arduino is 16 MHz. This means 16.000.000 cycli/s. That means for every pixel processing only 53 cycli are available. And using those external SRAMs will probably need much more.

A Raspberry is much more suitable for this task.